# How to not exceed max statements when using React hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, eslint

I noticed since I switch to using React hooks instead of HOCs, the number of statements in my simple components have increased drastically.
I used to have

```
// index.js
export default compose(
  withRouter,
  connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps),
  withData({ ..config }),
  withTranslation()
)(MyStatelessComponent);
```

And now I have

```
const MyStatefulComponent = () => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { items, removeItem, addItem } = useContext(ConnectionContext);
  // even more hooks

  return (<h1>Component body</h1>);

};
```

I mean I need to call so many hooks before I can implement a couple of event handlers and the main logic of the component.
Although hooks are great ways to compartmentalize the business logic, but they overcrowd the React component.
We have an Eslint 10 statements cap for arrow functions, and since the hooks, I find myself more often having to disable this rule.

Do you face this problem? Do you event consider this a problem? If so, what is your solution?